# Can I create PrimeFaces autocomplete which be suggest words on request?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can I create primefaces autocomplete which be suggest words on request?

For example, user write wanted word into a input and next click button which start suggest words.

Can I create this by uses primefaces autocomplete or I must create it from scratch?

Comment: You seem to know about PrimeFaces autocomplete. Why did you not just try?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following link:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

It shows how to implement autocomplete using Primefaces 5.2.10 on Mojorra 2.2.8